# Selenium - generating random number

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, random, numbers, generator

This is my code:

```
int index = (int)(Math.random()*15);
```

I want to generate numbers between 20 and 30, instead of just counting till 15. How do I do that?

Comment: Get a random number between 0 and 10 and add 20 to the result?

Answer (score 1):

In Java 1.7 or later the standard way to generate random numbers between **20** and **30** in a loop would be to use [`nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt-int-int-) from the *ThreadLocalRandom* module of **java.util.concurrent** as follows :

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Java_Generate_Random_Number {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(20, 30 + 1);
            System.out.println(randomNum);
        }
    }
}
```

Console Output :

```
28
27
30
20
24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((int)(Math.random()*11)+20);
```

Since you're after a range of 11 (20 to 30 inclusive), then your multiplier applied to the 'random' command is 11.
Since your minimum is 20, then you simply add 20, to that result.
Hope this works for you!

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use below java code:

```
int number = new Random().nextInt(11) + 20
```

You can also use below method to generate a random number between any range.

```
private static int getRandomNumberInRange(int min, int max) {

    if (min >= max) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("max must be greater than min");
    }

    Random r = new Random();
    return r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}
```

Just call this method like `getRandomNumberInRange(20, 30)`.

Comment: I tried it.. but it is not working.. is there some work around the  int index = (int)(Math.random()*15); Sorry I am a new user..by mistake I pushed the not useful button for your solution code.